# Render element on a page with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Taking my first steps in React. Please help to display this part:

```
{
  incidents.forEach(incidents => {
    incidents.map(inc =>{
      return (
        <div key={inc.id} className='inc'>
          <div className='incDescr'>Description: {inc.title}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
  })
}
```

in the code below.

```
import React from 'react';

const api_url = 'http://localhost:8080';
const errorHandler = error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false });

class AllIncidents extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            incidents: [],
            error: null
        };
    }

    getIncidents() {
        fetch(api_url + '/incident/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({
                    incidents: [data],
                    isLoading: false
                })
            ).catch(errorHandler);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getIncidents();
    }

    render() {
        const { incidents, error } = this.state;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>All Incidents</h1>
                {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}

                {
                    incidents.forEach(incidents => {
                        incidents.map(inc =>{
                            return (
                                <div key={inc.id} className='inc'>
                                    <div className='incDescr'>Description: {inc.title}</div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    })
                }
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default AllIncidents;
```

Response from the back-end:

```
[{"id":"5d923ecd9a65603e8bd1022f","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fc49a65603e8bd10230","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fc79a65603e8bd10231","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fc89a65603e8bd10232","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fc99a65603e8bd10233","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fca9a65603e8bd10234","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fcb9a65603e8bd10235","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fcc9a65603e8bd10236","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fcd9a65603e8bd10237","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fcd9a65603e8bd10238","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fce9a65603e8bd10239","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fcf9a65603e8bd1023a","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd09a65603e8bd1023b","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd19a65603e8bd1023c","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd19a65603e8bd1023d","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd29a65603e8bd1023e","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd39a65603e8bd1023f","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd39a65603e8bd10240","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd49a65603e8bd10241","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd59a65603e8bd10242","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd59a65603e8bd10243","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd69a65603e8bd10244","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd79a65603e8bd10245","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null},{"id":"5d923fd79a65603e8bd10246","title":"Incident 6","description":null,"status":null}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over your array twice, try removing the incidents.forEach so the code looks like this:

```
{incidents.map(inc => (
  <div key={inc.id} className='inc'>
    <div className='incDescr'>Description: {inc.title}</div>
  </div>
))}
```

Edit: To address your issue with cannot read setState of undefined, you need to bind your functions.  Defining your fetch method as an arrow function should do the trick.  Alternatively you could bind the function in your constructor.

```
getIncidents = () => {
  fetch(api_url + '/incident/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
      incidents: data,
      isLoading: false
    }))
    .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: In this case, if I console.log(inc), I see an object list. That's why I used forEach before.

Comment: Ahhh, could you try modifying your setState where you fetch the data?  I think you are wrapping the response in an additional array. Try incidents: data, instead of incidents: [data].

Comment: in this case, I receive Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.

Comment: Added an edit which modifies your function to an arrow function.  This should resolve the setState of undefined error.